# Performing a function to check for duplicates before saving the record in the model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

This is what I have in my model. I want to check for duplicate records and I cant just use a unique index for a field since the contacts are unique per job) I am unable to do this using the following code. Am I doing it wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
before_save :check_for_duplicates?

def check_for_duplicates?
  JobsPeople.find(:all, :conditions => ["job_id = ? and contact_id = ?", self.job_id, self.contact_id])
end
```

Comment: Can you not use a composite unique index on `(job_id, contact_id)`?

Comment: Just fyi, remember that using such filters does not guarantee uniqueness. Most times, it is not a catastrophic problem if there is a duplicated of some record, but sometimes it is catastrophic - and you want to ensure uniqueness at the DB-level in those cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Callbacks don't do anything more than run the code you tell them to run. If you want to prevent something from executing you have two options, use a validation or raise an error.

In your current code you could check if that query you ran returns anything, and then raise an error if it does. The error will bubble up to the transaction that is wrapping the save and trigger a rollback, then propagate the error into your code where you can handle it if you want.

```
before_save :check_for_duplicates?

def check_for_duplicates?
  if JobsPeople.find(:all, :conditions => ["job_id = ? and contact_id = ?", self.job_id, self.contact_id]).any?
    raise 'some error'
  end
end
```

Although there is already a built-in uniqueness validator that handles this situation

```
validates :job_id, :uniquness => {:scope => :contact_id, :message => 'must be unique per contact}
```

Of course this should still be backed up with a composite unique index in the database as there is a potential race condition, the likelihood of which depends largely on the behavior of your application.

```
# in a migration

add_index :table_name, [:job_id, :contact_id], :unique => true, :name => 'index_job_id_and_contact_id_on_table_name'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Cluster! I have a question regarding the composite index. Does that line in the migration make it so that the contact_id is unique per job_id?

Comment: That's right. The database creates an index that concatenates the two fields, so a job id of 140 and contact id of 300 would have something like '140-300'. Of course the actual value will depend on the database, just using that as an example.

Comment: Ah, that clearly explains how a composite index works. I did not know it was concatenating behind the scenes. Thank you! I am learning new ways to do things with rails!!

Answer (score 7):

I believe this should do what you want

```
class JobsPeople
  validates_uniqueness_of :contact_id, scope: :job_id
end
```